# Sencha add dynamically tap listener to record list

Tags: list, cordova, sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I have an Ext.data.Store and a Ext.Panel with a list.
I add record dynamically with this command:

```
myStore.add({txt: r});
```

I would like to add a listener that when I click on a list record, it shows me the record data in a message box.

How can I do it?

Ext.data.store

```
   var myStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        storeId: 'MyStore',
        fields: ['txt']
    }); // create()
```

Ext.Panel

```
listpanel = new Ext.Panel({
                            layout: 'fit',   // important to make layout as 'fit'
                            items: [
                                {
                                    xtype: 'titlebar',
                                    id: 'myTitle',
                                    docked: 'top',
                                    title: 'Before Change title'

                                },
                                {
                                  //Definition of the list
                                  xtype: 'list',
                                  itemTpl: '{txt}',
                                  store: myStore,
                                }]
                          });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `itemtap` event of the `Ext.List` component.

E.g

```
   ....
   ....
   xtype: 'list',
   itemTpl: '{txt}',
   store: myStore,
   listeners : {
         itemtap : function(item, num, record, ev) {
                var myTxt = item.getStore().getAt(num).get('txt');
                Ext.Msg.alert('Message','Tapped record : '+myTxt);
         }
   }
   ....
   ....
```